# Python sys.argv in a regression

Tags: python, pandas, sys

I am new to Python and trying to use sys.argv in my codes but I don't understand it.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
df = pd.read_csv('german_credit_data.csv')
df.rename(columns = {'Credit amount':'Credit_amount'}, inplace = True)

df = df[['Credit_amount','Age','Duration']]
X = df[['Age','Duration']]
Y = df[['Credit_amount']]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()

print(model.params.round(2))
print(model.rsquared.round(2))
```

There is nothing wrong with my code but I have to add a sys.argv in this without changing the answer. How do I do that?

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by you need to add ```sys.argv``` to your code?  What information would be providing with ```sys.argv```?

Comment: `sys.argv` is the list of command-line arguments passed to your program. How you use `sys.argv` depends on what arguments you plan for the caller to provide.

Comment: I'm doing several python projects and they all require that I include a sys.argv in each one. I don't understand HOW to use it though.